# CSS ::after styling affecting vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

[Image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbaJg.png)

[Image showing the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI2fu.png)

I have three lines of text describing a user, which are centrally aligned.

Now I seek to add an icon to the username, which I have done using ::after styling in CSS (see below).

However, this then is considered when centering the first line. What I'd ideally like is for the username to be aligned centrally with the rest of the text and to then place the icon to the right of that without affecting the alignment at all.

How can I do this?

HTML

```
              <div class="user-name">
                <p> David Wood </p>
              </div>
              <p class="user-type"> Teacher </p>
              <p class="user-email"> d.wood@school.ac.uk</p>
```

(part of my) CSS

```
.user-name p::after {
  content: '';
  background: url('homeimages/dropdown-black.png') left center no-repeat;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-size: 10px auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top:-20px;
  white-space:pre;
}
```

Comment: make it position:absolute

Comment: @TemaniAfif Unfortunately, that just causes the icon to disappear :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way you used `flex` to align your user elements, you can do the same with the `<p>` element within username.

```
.username p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

This will ensure that all the elements within the `.username p {}` element will be aligned vertically. Be aware, this is only the case if the `flex-direction` of your element is default, to `flex-direction: row`. If, for any reason however, you were using `flex-direction: column` you would use `justify-content: center` for vertical alignment.

P.s I often use https://fontawesome.com/ to get icons. Using their inline `<i>` icon elements as siblings of text, wrapped with a flex parent, often makes for a nice, clean look too. For instance

```
<a class="flex-container"><i class="fas fa-users"></i>Buy</a>
```

Comment: @BenDerby this will give different result  from what you are showing, you should make your question more clear then

Answer (score -1):

Use more `<div>`s and use `<img>` tags for images. So the code should look something like this

```
<div class="col-md-6">User Name</div>
<div col-md-6><img></img>
<div col-md-6> <p class="user-type"> Teacher </p> </div>
<div col-md-6> <p class="user-email"> d.wood@school.ac.uk</p> </div>
```

Comment: How do I then position than img next to the username? I am not using bootstrap and then CSS grid has one column in my case.